# Retrofit @QueryMap with proguard

Tags: android, proguard, retrofit

When I run the application with proguard enabled, the `@QueryMap` query strings are not being appended to the main URL.
The interface function is:

```java
@GET(PATH_HEADER + "/function/")
ServiceLoginResponse function( @QueryMap Map options );
```

With log enabled, with proguard, this is the request:

```
com.app D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP GET https://domain.com/json/function/
com.app D/Retrofit﹕ Cache-Control: public, max-age=600
com.app D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (no body)
```

Without proguard:

```
com.app D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP GET https://domain.com/json/function/?param1=val1&param2=val2
com.app D/Retrofit﹕ Cache-Control: public, max-age=600
com.app D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (no body)
```

And in my Proguard rules file I have this;

```
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For retrofit you need to keep annotations. For that add this rule:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Then you need your rule to keep Retrofit classes:

```
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
```

And you probably need to keep your REST API and its API methods:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
```